# Probability of Difference of Two independent normal random variables

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Can $P(Z_{1}>0,Z_{2}>0)$ be written as $P(X_{1}>0,X_{2}>0)$, if $Z_{1}=X_{1}-Y_{1}$, where $X_{1} \sim N(0,1)$ & is independent of $Y_{1}\sim N(0,1)$, $Z_{2}$ is defined in same way as $Z_{1}$ i.e. $Z_{2}=X_{2}-Y_{2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\rho:=\operatorname{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$. If $\operatorname{Cov}(Y_1,Y_2)=\rho$ as well, that is, $(Y_1,Y_2)$ is an independent copy of $(X_1,X_2)$, then
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\begin{bmatrix}
X_1-Y_1 \\
X_2-Y_2
\end{bmatrix}\sim N\!\left(0, \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho \\
\rho & 1
\end{bmatrix}\right),
$$
and the probabilities are equal.